# Issue on Implementing Back Navigation in React Router Dom

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am having an issue with implementing a back navigation using react-router-dom.
It outputs `A history only accepts one active listener`

CODESANDBOX: [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-go-back-one-page-only-if-the-page-is-within-the-site-in-react-router-dom-forked-u3dnhm?file=/src/NavigateContext.js:0-1668)

```
import {
  createContext,
  useCallback,
  useContext,
  useEffect,
  useState
} from "react";
import {
  useNavigate as useNavigateBase,
  UNSAFE_NavigationContext,
  NavigationType
} from "react-router-dom";

export const NavigateContext = createContext({
  navigate: () => {}
});

export const useNavigate = () => useContext(NavigateContext);

// eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types
const NavigateProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [historyStack, setHistoryStack] = useState([]);

  const navigate = useNavigateBase();

  const { navigator } = useContext(UNSAFE_NavigationContext);

  useEffect(() => {
    const listener = ({ location, action }) => {
      switch (action) {
        case NavigationType.Push:
          return setHistoryStack((stack) => stack.concat(location));

        case NavigationType.Replace:
          return setHistoryStack((stack) =>
            stack.slice(0, -1).concat(location)
          );

        case NavigationType.Pop:
          return setHistoryStack((stack) => stack.slice(0, -1));

        default:
        // ignore
      }
    };

    return navigator.listen(listener);
  }, [navigator]);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ historyStack });
  }, [historyStack]);

  const navigateHandler = useCallback(
    (arg, options) => {
      if (typeof arg === "number" && arg < 0 && !historyStack.length) {
        navigate("/", { replace: true });
      } else {
        navigate(arg, options);
      }
    },
    [historyStack, navigate]
  );

  return (
    <NavigateContext.Provider value={{ navigate: navigateHandler }}>
      {children}
    </NavigateContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default NavigateProvider;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The newer `react-router-dom@6.4+` routers are based on Remix routers, and they have locked down access to the navigator a bit more. Instead of importing a `BrowserRouter` you can use the `HistoryRouter` and provide your own history object. For this you'll also need to add `history@5` as a project dependency.

```
npm install --save history@5
```

index.js

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";

// Import the HistoryRouter
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as Router } from "react-router-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history"; // v5
import App from "./App";

// Create a browser history object
export const history = createBrowserHistory();

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <Router history={history}> // <-- pass history to Router
      <App />
    </Router>
  </StrictMode>
);
```

[image: Edit issue-on-implementing-back-navigation-in-react-router-dom]

Comment: @Joseph The `NavigateProvider` should provide the custom navigate function directly, not wrapped in an object, e.g. `<NavigateContext.Provider value={navigateHandler}>{children}</NavigateContext.Provider>`, and then in your routed components import the custom function `import { useNavigate } from "./NavigateContext";` and `const navigate = useNavigate();` just like the base `useNavigate` hook from RRD. I've updated the sandbox. I believe it should work the same in a vite app.

Comment: @Joseph Material-UI `Link` components aren't the same thing as `react-router` `Link` components. RRD won't be aware of any navigation actions they effect. If you want to use Material-UI link and *really* render a RRD `Link` component then `import { Link as LinkBase } from 'react-router-dom'` and `<Link component={LinkBase} to="/" underline="hover">{value}</Link>`.

Comment: @Joseph When you reload the page you are starting an entirely new browser session. The React app is reloaded, all the React states are reset unless you are persisting any state to localStorage and setting the initial state values from localStorage.

Comment: Hi Drew. Just notice theres an issue when I integrated this on my app. The browser back button cant be click anymore

Comment: @Joseph Have you a running sandbox demo?

Comment: Here it is.

I added some query params to it. It should be like that.

```<Link to={`/page/${page}?page=0&pageSize=10&queries=%5B%7B`}>```

https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-on-implementing-back-navigation-in-react-router-dom-forked-sofr3p?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Joseph All the navigation actions appear to be working. The browser's back button and the rendered "Sports [back]" back button navigate back. What exactly is the issue? What is a good repro?

Comment: pls click a certain page and refresh that page. You cant go back anymore

Comment: Have you replicated the issue?

Comment: @Joseph No, I have not replicated the issue you describe. I can navigate a few of the links, check the browser's history stack and see the entries, reload the page, see the entries still in the browser's history stack, and use both the browser's back button and the "Sports [Back]" button in the UI to issue a back navigation.

Comment: Is this the link you tested?

https://codesandbox.io/s/issue-on-implementing-back-navigation-in-react-router-dom-forked-sofr3p?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Joseph If that is the same sandbox as linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75233649/issue-on-implementing-back-navigation-in-react-router-dom/75237629?noredirect=1#comment133576463_75237629) then yes, it's what I tested with.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252503/discussion-between-drew-reese-and-joseph).